# Print first 100 words of a text before ellipsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, text

If I have some `text` that I want to print out on a page, but only want to print say the first 100 words before eclipsing it... what's the easiest way to do this?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that "eclipsing" is not the word you want. It does mean "obscure", but only in the astronomical sense. "Ellipsis", which you don't seem to like, is the name for the three-dot think: "..."

Comment: Ellipsis really *is* the word you are looking for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How's this for a start:

```
def first_words(s, n)
  a = s.split(/\s/) # or /[ ]+/ to only split on spaces
  a[0...n].join(' ') + (a.size > n ? '...' : '')
end

s = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. " * 20

puts "#{s.size}, #{s.split(/\s/).size}" 
#-> 900, 180

puts first_words(s, 10)
#-> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The...

puts first_words("a b c d", 10)
#-> a b c d
```

Comment: This seems to remove my new lines. How do I keep them?

Comment: Ah. \s matches "whitespace", which includes newlines. Try changing the /\s/ to / / (one space) or possibly /[ ]+/ (which matches one or more spaces) if there may be more than one space together.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options, one way is that you could say that a word is *n* characters and then take a substring of that length, append the [ellipsis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) to the end and display it. Or you could run though the string and count the number of spaces, if you assume that there is only one space between each of the words, then the 100th space will be after then 100th word, append the ellipsis and you are done.

Which one has better performance would likely depend upon how the functions are written, most likely the substring operation is going to be faster than counting the spaces. However, the performance difference might be negligible so unless you are doing this a lot, counting spaces would likely be the most accurate way to go.

Also, just as a reference, the average length of a word in the English language [is 5.1 characters](http://blogamundo.net/lab/wordlengths/).

Answer (score 0):

```
text.slice(0..100)
if text.size > 100 then puts "..."
```

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html

Comment: That would be the first 100 characters, not the first 100 words.