# Rails: Smart text truncation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, text, truncate

I wonder if there's a plugin to enable a sort of smart truncation. I need to truncate my text with a precision of a word or of a sentence.

For example:

```
Post.my_message.smart_truncate(
    "Once upon a time in a world far far away. And they found that many people
     were sleeping better.", :sentences => 1)
# => Once upon a time in a world far far away.
```

or

```
Post.my_message.smart_truncate(
    "Once upon a time in a world far far away. And they found that many people
     were sleeping better.", :words => 12)
# => Once upon a time in a world far far away. And they ...
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I haven't seen such a plugin, but there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747238) that could serve as the basis for a lib or helper function.

The way you show the function seems to put it as an extension to String: unless you really want to be able to do this outside of a view, I'd be inclined to go for a function in `application_helper.rb`. Something like this, perhaps?

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def smart_truncate(s, opts = {})
    opts = {:words => 12}.merge(opts)
    if opts[:sentences]
      return s.split(/\.(\s|$)+/)[0, opts[:sentences]].map{|s| s.strip}.join('. ') + '.'
    end
    a = s.split(/\s/) # or /[ ]+/ to only split on spaces
    n = opts[:words]
    a[0...n].join(' ') + (a.size > n ? '...' : '')
  end
end

smart_truncate("a b c. d e f. g h i.", :sentences => 2) #=> "a b c. d e f."
smart_truncate("apple blueberry cherry plum", :words => 3) #=> "apple blueberry cherry..."
```

Comment: Oh, that was a really good answer! Thanks a lot!
Now I see a real reason to increase my knowledge in regular expressions.

Comment: It doesn't work as expected with sentences. It adds to much separators (dots) between sentences.

Comment: This works: `return s.split(/\.(\s|$)+/).reject{ |s| s.strip.empty? }[0, opts[:sentences]].map{|s| s.strip}.join('. ') + '...'`

Answer (score 8):

This will truncate at the word boundary based on the char_limit length specified. So it will not truncate the sentence at weird places

```
def smart_truncate(text, char_limit)
    size = 0
    text.split().reject do |token|
      size += token.size() + 1
      size > char_limit
    end.join(' ') + ( text.size() > char_limit ? ' ' + '...' : '' )
end
```

Comment: This doesn't current include spaces in the character count. It should have size += token.size + 1 if you want to account for spaces.

Comment: You should edit your answer to include space before the question mark as the short syntax for if else statement is syntactically wrong.

Comment: I've edited the above code to reflect the bugs mentioned in the comments. It seems to be working correctly on my system

Answer (score 1):

The gem [truncate_html](http://rubygems.org/gems/truncate_html) does this job. It also can skip over pieces of HTML – which can be quiet useful – and offers the possibility to customize the word boundary regex. Furthermore the defaults for all parameters can be configured eg in your `config/environment.rb`.

**Example:**

```
some_html = '<ul><li><a href="http://whatever">This is a link</a></li></ul>'

truncate_html(some_html, :length => 15, :omission => '...(continued)')
=> <ul><li><a href="http://whatever">This...(continued)</a></li></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice helper. Since I had a different experience I did change it so that it stops on the last word and work with character limit. I think this is much more real world scenario in most apps.

Update: Took the code above and updated it a bit. Seemed much nicer approach for old ruby and works with utf8.

```
def smart_truncate(text, char_limit)
  text = text.squish
  size = 0
  text.mb_chars.split().reject do |token|
    size+=token.size()
    size>char_limit
  end.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Actually looking at soulofpeace code it does allow work with utf8 and mb_chars. So I took his code and improved a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Working for quite a while now on some updates with different projects and I came up with these refinements of the code that seem much more usable in real life scenarios.

```
def smart_truncate_characters(text, char_limit)
  text = text.to_s
  text = text.squish
  size = 0
  new_text = text.mb_chars.split().reject do |token|
    size+=token.size()
    size>char_limit
  end.join(" ")
  if size > char_limit
    return new_text += '…'
  else
    return new_text
  end
end

def smart_truncate_sentences(text, sentence_limit)
  text = text.to_s
  text = text.squish
  size = 0
  arr = text.mb_chars.split(/(?:\.|\?|\!)(?= [^a-z]|$)/)
  arr = arr[0...sentence_limit]
  new_text = arr.join(".")
  new_text += '.'
end

def smart_truncate(text, sentence_limit, char_limit)
  text =  smart_truncate_sentences(text, sentence_limit)
  text =  smart_truncate_characters(text, char_limit)
end
```

Comment: You can also do `ActionController::Base.helpers.strip_tags(text)` if you want to strip any tags that might get passed along with that text if you do prefer so.